# How to change CardLayout panels from a separate panel?

Tags: java, swing, oop, layout-manager, cardlayout

My software layout is kinda wizard-base. So the base panel is divided into two `JPanel`s. One left panel which never changes. And one right panel that works with `CardLayout`. It has many sub-panels and show each one of them by a method.

I can easily go from one inner panel to another one. But I want to have a button in left panel and change panels of the right side.

Here is a sample code which you can run it:

**BASE:**

```
public class Base {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Panel");
        BorderLayout bl = new BorderLayout();

    public Base(){
        frame.setLayout(bl);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.add(new LeftBar(), BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(new MainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        new Base();
    }
}
```

**Left side**

```
public class LeftBar extends JPanel{
    JButton button;
    MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();

    public LeftBar(){
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 40));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setBackground(Color.black);

        button = new JButton("Show Second Page");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
               mainPanel.showPanel("secondPage");
           }

       });

       add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
}
```

**Right Side**

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    private CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
    private JPanel panelHolder = new JPanel(cl);

    public MainPanel(){
        FirstPage firstPage = new FirstPage(this);
        SecondPage secondPage = new SecondPage(this);

        setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

        panelHolder.add(firstPage, "firstPage");
        panelHolder.add(secondPage, "secondPage");

        cl.show(panelHolder, "firstPage");
        add(panelHolder);

    }
    public void showPanel(String panelIdentifier){
        cl.show(panelHolder, panelIdentifier);
    }
}
```

**Inner panels for right side:**

```
public class FirstPage extends JPanel {
    MainPanel mainPanel;
    JButton button;

    public FirstPage(MainPanel mainPanel) {
       this.mainPanel = mainPanel;
       setBackground(Color.GRAY);

       button = new JButton("Show page");
       button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
               mainPanel.showPanel("secondPage");
           }

       });

       add(button);
    }
}



public class SecondPage extends JPanel{
    MainPanel mainPanel;
    JButton button;
    public SecondPage(MainPanel mainPanel){
       this.mainPanel = mainPanel;
        setBackground(Color.white);
       add(new JLabel("This is second page"));
    }
}
```

And this is a picture to give you the idea:
[image]

As I explained, I can travel *"from first"* page to *"second page"* by using this method: `mainPanel.showPanel("secondPage");` or `mainPanel.showPanel("firstPage");`.

But I also have a `JButton` in the left bar, which I call the same method to show the second panel of the CardLayout. But it does not work. It doesnt give any error though.

Any idea how to change these `CardLayout` panels from outside of panels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `LeftBar` has `mainPanel` member that is initialized to a new instance of `MainPanel`. So you have two instances of `MainPanel`, one allocated in `Base` and added to the frame, the other one allocated in `LeftBar`.

So `LeftBar` executes `mainPanel.showPanel("secondPage");` on a second instance of `MainPanel` which is not even a part of a visual hierarchy. To fix this just pass an existing instance of `MainPanel` to the constructor of `LeftBar`. You already do this in `FirstPage` and `SecondPage`.

Comment: I have another problem similar with this one. But I made a separate question for that. Can you have a look please? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597973/why-doesnt-actionlistener-work-in-the-controller)